# varchar Fields - Is a Power of Two More Efficient?

Tags: database-design, varchar

Is it more efficient to use a `varchar` field sized as a power of two vs. another number? I'm thinking no, because for SQL Server the default is 50.

However, I've heard (but never confirmed) that sizing fields as a power of 2 is more efficient because they equate to even bytes, and computers process in bits & bytes.

So, does a field declared as `varchar(32)` or `varchar(64)` have any real benefit over `varchar(50)`?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**No.**

In some other uses, there are some advantages to use structures with a power of two size, mostly because you can fit a nice (power of two) number of these inside another power-of-two-sized structure. But this doesn't apply to a DB fieldsize.

The only power-of-two-sizing related to VARCHARs is about the exact type of varchar (or TEXT/BLOB in some SQL dialects): if it's less than 256, it can use a single byte to indicate length.  if it's less than 65536 (64KB), two bytes are enough, three bytes work up to 16777216 (16MB), four bytes go to 4294967296 (4GB).

Also, it can be argued that `VARCHAR(50)` is just as expensive as `VARCHAR(255)`, since both will need n+1 bytes of storage.

Of course that's before thinking of Unicode...

Answer (score 39):

I always thought people choose powers of two for varchar fields because we're geeks and that's what we do.  At least that's what I've always done.

Comment: I agree, but how would you reflect that char limit in the UI? Seeing `n/1000` (next to a text field) might make more sense than seeing `n/1024` to a common user. The user might go "What's with the 24?"

Comment: @akinuri these days I use Postgresql, where the is no reason to limit a varchar field length at all - a varchar(100) and a varchar(1000000) field take up the same amount of space if there's only 99 characters in it.

Answer (score 5):

For SQL in general? No. For a specific implementation, maybe.

What is more efficient is not determined by a specification (SQL is just a specification), but how it is implemented in a certain DBMS.

Comment: One possible place for this to occur would be in the in-memory format for rows...2^n lengths should reduce the need for alignment offsets. Usually a small effect, I suspect.

Comment: Memory alignment happens in multiples, not in powers. On a 32-bit aligned architecture, the best byte offsets are 4×n, for example.

Answer (score 4):

The only tangible benefit you will see from using certain maximum lengths is the storage space required for the `VARCHAR`. A maximum length over 255 would require an extra byte to store the length of the value in each row (and an extra 2 bytes for lengths of 256^2 or greater and so on).

Comment: wouldn't it be 256*2 ?

Comment: @Realn0whereman No, 256*2 would only require an extra bit. 8 bits can store values between 0 and 255 (assuming unsigned values here), an extra bit doubles that to 0-511. An extra byte (8 bits) takes that to 2^16 possible values, or 0-65535, ie. anything below 256^2.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the specific database implementation, but I wouldn't expect it to.  It's not performing any calculations on the number of characters, generally, so it shouldn't affect performance - only space.